# Display product and related images in the view, using repository pattern mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am trying to create a view to display product information and its related images. I am using repository pattern,

please see the code below, I will really appreciate your help

```
public class ProductDetail
    {
        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string pro_name { get; set; }              
        public string pro_model { get; set; }
        public string pro_Dimensions { get; set; }            
        public string pro_imageTitle { get; set; }
        public string pro_image { get; set; }               
        public string pro_desc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_price { get; set; }         
        public int pro_UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> pro_oldprice { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<Images> tbl_Images { get; set; }

    }

 public class Images
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }

 public class ProductDetailRepository : IProductDetail
    {
        private readonly WebStoreEntities storeDB;

        public ProductDetailRepository() { }

        public ProductDetailRepository(WebStoreEntities _storeDB)
        {
            this.storeDB = _storeDB;
        }


public ProductDetail GetProductByID(int id)
        {
          
            var prod = storeDB.tbl_Product
                         .Where(x => x.pro_id == id)
                         .Include(p => p.tbl_Images)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
           
            return prod;  (Here it says, cannot implicitly convert type tbl_product to productdetail (this is where i need help))
        }
```

tbl_product is from the EDMX model.
}

now, i am stcuk in this method, all i want is to return the product info and related images to the controller and then view.

Comment: I'd recommend revising your question to be more focused on your particular problem, thus ensuring that the people most knowledgeable with this problem can chime in. Specifically, your issue really has nothing to do with ASP.NET or displaying the information in the view, but rather converting the return type from your `WebStoreEntities.tbl_Product` call into your `ProductDetail` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to convert your `tbl_Product` that you get from the database into the `ProductDetail` you want to return:

```
public ProductDetail GetProductByID(int id)
{
    var prod = storeDB.tbl_Product
                      .Where(x => x.pro_id == id)
                      .Include(p => p.tbl_Images)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

    if (prod == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    ProductDetail result = new ProductDetail
                               {
                                   // I'm just *GUESSING* here since you haven't showed
                                   // the tbl_product class, so I don't know what the 
                                   // properties on that class are called, really...
                                   pro_id = prod.Id,
                                   pro_name = prod.Name
                                   // and so on for all the properties
                               }

    return result;
}
```